# Animation that moves image forward, at the same time flips, to give the impression of walking forward

Tags: animation

I have looked for an animation that moves image forward, at the same time flips and grows, to give the impression of walking forward. I tried creating this in photoshop, which works, but I couldn't resolve the problem of the space it takes up, disrupting other more important items on the page. I have tried adapting the 'rocket' from http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/  but don't know enough to add the flip I will add image to show what i am trying to do. - ok it seems I dont have enough reputation to post images, but i dont know how to get reputation!!  Images would appear consecutively left to right.

This is not the image I will be using but demonstrates what I need. The one I will be using is copyright. All except the front center image is the same image (when I use my original there will be four different images center front).

**Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: Could you offer, say, a storyboard or pencil sketch that describes the movement you're looking for?

Comment: Hi Katana314, I had an image to add but dont have enough reputation. Can you imagine a horse coming towards you but it will go past your left shoulder, the next image will be the same but flipped and horse will go past right shoulder- it is slightly larger. Repeat, say, six times. Then there is a different image (horse is rearing), then original images are reversed, returning almost to original start point. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var thething = document.querySelector('.thething');
  thething.style.transform = 'perspective(500px) rotateY(80deg) translateX(-500px)';
 }, 1000);
```

```css
.thething {
  background-color: red;
  transition: transform 5s;
  transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(80deg);
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="thething"></div>
```

This is generally what it might take to do the animation; I know it's not quite as involved as what you described in your comment, but largely it would involve a lot of grunt work and changing the numbers around. Let me know if there's anything critical here that you'd have trouble theorizing a way to do it.